# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery

so my code below works stand alone in a jsfiddle. but for some odd reason.. I get this error consistently after pushing it to a live server :/ and I can't figure out why...

**error**:

```
mycodewitherror.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

**js:**

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// The below collects user login name, new login date and time, and previous use URL
var element = document.querySelector('.pet-name'); 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      var username = $('.pet-name').text();
      var referrer = document.referrer;
      var date = new Date();
      var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
      var day = date.getUTCDate();
      var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
      var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      var formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    console.log("Pet Name Time"); 
      console.log(referrer); 
      console.log(petname); 
      console.log(time); 
      console.log(formattedDate);   
});

// configuration of the observer:

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(element, config);
```

Comment: In both 'element' references?

Comment: No just when you call `observer.observe()`. Oh wait wait, no I'm totally wrong.

Comment: OK, well are you sure that there's an element on the page with class "pet-name"? If not, then `element` will be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: Well the pet-name will be present on some pages, but not all...

Comment: Well then you probably need to check: `if (element) observer.observe(...)`

Comment: hm.. Well. let me try that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered the same error, and solved it by calling the `.observe()` method inside the `onload/ready` code-block instead of the observer var definition, plus the definition of `target` element and `config` variables:

Please run the code snippet below, click the "Add list item" button and watch the change log in the console.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var target = document.getElementById("myList");
    var config = {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true,
        characterData: true
    };
    //note this observe method call
    observer.observe(target, config);
    console.log("Observer is registered");
});

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutationRecords, observer) {
    mutationRecords.forEach(function (mutation) {
        console.log("mutation change in ", mutation.type, " name: ",mutation.target);
    });
});

function add() {
    var index = $("ul li").length;
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.textContent = index + 1;
    var target = document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(listItem, "before");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body >
    <button onclick="add()">Add list item</button>
    <hr>
    <ul id="myList">
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    </ul>
    
</body>
```